# If $x=u^3+v^3$ and $y=u*v-v^2$ are solved for $u$ and $v$ in terms of $x$ and $y$, evaluate $\partial u/\partial x$ at $(u,v)=(1,1)$

Tags: calculus, systems-of-equations, partial-derivative, implicit-differentiation

If $x=u^3+v^3$ and $y=u*v-v^2$ are solved for $u$ and $v$ in terms of $x$ and $y$, evaluate $\partial u/\partial x$ at the point where $u = 1$ and $v = 1$.

It also asks me to evaluate $\partial u/\partial y$, $\partial v/\partial x$, $\partial v/\partial y$, and $\partial (u,v)/\partial (x,y)$ for the same $u = 1$ and $v = 1$.

I am not sure at all what to do here. I did try and get $u$ and $v$ on one side, but the expression is so ridiculously long that I don't think I did it right... help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the point $p:=(1,1)$ the map
$$f:\quad (u,v)\mapsto\left\{\eqalign{x&=u^3+v^3\cr y&=uv-v^2\cr}\right.$$
is *regular*, because the  determinant of the Jacobian
$$J_f(u,v)=\left[{\partial(x,y)\over\partial(u,v)}\right]=\left[\matrix{3u^2&3v^2\cr v&u-2v\cr}\right]$$
at $p$ is given by
$$\det J_f(p)=\det\left[\matrix{3&3\cr 1&-1\cr}\right]=-6\ne0\ .$$
According to the implicit function theorem this implies that $f$ maps a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ bijectively onto a neighborhood $V$ of the point $q:=f(p)=(2,0)$, and the inverse map $g:\>V\to U$ is again differentiable at $q$. Furthermore $$dg(q)=\bigl(df(p)\bigr)^{-1}\ ,$$ hence the Jacobian of $g$ at $q$ is given by
$$J_g(q)=\bigl(J_f(p)\bigr)^{-1}=\left[\matrix{3&3\cr 1&-1\cr}\right]^{-1}=\left[\matrix{{1\over6}&{1\over2}\cr {1\over6}&-{1\over2}\cr}\right]\ .$$
The last matrix is already the matrix
$$\left[\matrix{u_x&u_y\cr v_x&v_y\cr}\right]_q\ ,$$
and this gives the answers to all your questions.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation!